# How can use switch case statement using class names as case in php?

Tags: php, class, switch-statement, case

Is there a way to use the class names as cases in the folowing example? (pseudo code)

```
class Some_Class {

    static function get_image_size() {

        switch (get_class($image_size)) {

            case 'Class_1':
                        $image_size = 'related-post';
                        break;
                    }
            case 'Class_2':
                        $image_size = 'full';
                        break;
                    }                   

                        return $image_size;

                    }

}
```

I need this to call a specific variable form different php classes.
Basically I need something like the following code but using switch statement:

```
class Some_class {

    static function get_image_size() {

        if Class_Name_1 {
            $image_size = 'related-post';
        }

        elseif Class_Name_2 {
            $image_size = 'full';
        }                   

        return $image_size;

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you want. Best guess: `switch (get_class($image_size))`...?!

Comment: If *what* `Class_Name_1`...?! Still doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first, if this "class name" thing is the name of a class where you call this function why not passing it as a variable to this static function?

Second, if by class name you mean name of the "Some_Class", you might be able to access to this name through this code in a static function:

```
$thisClassName = get_class(new self());
```

!better:

```
$thisClassName = get_class();
```

or

```
$thisClassName = __CLASS__;
```

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of a class just to get its class name within itself. Just use `__CLASS__` or `get_class()`.